# Python sql alchemy cursor not select statement

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, cursor

i have developed this Database class to create more function to reuse in other file:

```
import threading
import sqlite3
from queue import Queue
import sqlalchemy

class Database(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, db, logger = None):
        super(Database, self).__init__()
        self.db=db
        self.reqs=Queue()
        self.log = logger
        self.start()
        self.join()
    
    def run(self):
        try:
            # create connection pool
            pool = sqlalchemy.create_engine("postgresql+pg8000://",creator=self.db,pool_size= 20,max_overflow= 0)
            cnx = pool.raw_connection()
            cursor = cnx.cursor()
            print('Conection DB')
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"[DB] An error occurred: {e}")
            return
        while True:
            req, arg, res = self.reqs.get()
            if req=='--close--': break
            cursor.execute(req, arg)
            if res:
                for rec in cursor:
                    res.put(rec)
                res.put('--no more--')
        cnx.close()

    def execute(self, req, arg=None, res=None):
        self.reqs.put((req, arg or tuple(), res))
    
    def sel(self, req, arg=None,res=None):
        self.execute(req, arg, res)

    def select(self, req, arg=None):
        res=Queue()
        self.execute(req, arg, res)
        while True:
            rec=res.get()
            if rec=='--no more--': break
            yield rec

    def close(self):
        self.execute('--close--')
```

now into other python file i try to call the select function in this way:

```
# initialize Connector object
connector = Connector()



def getconn():
    with Connector() as connector:
        conn = connector.connect(
            instance_connection_name,
            "pg8000",
            user = db_user,
            password = db_pass,
            db = db_name,
            ip_type = IPTypes.PUBLIC
        )
        return conn

def get_p(found:Database):
     #data = select("SELECT * FROM products")
     data = found.select("SELECT count(*) FROM products")
     
     return data

dbstore = Database(db=getconn)
try:
    
    print(get_p(dbstore))
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

into terminal i see that the connection message ('Conection DB') is printed but the sql statement into select function is not executed.

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is a little confusing, why are you not iterating over rows? it's a select statement right?

Comment: Hello Suchandra, the first select is commented. The second statement is a count, why i should iterate it?

Comment: Count(*) is a result with a single row returned. so iterating over a single row will fetch you the required count received from the SQL query.

Comment: Ok, but with iteration i have the same problem.